# How to split your foreach that will make 1000 loops and echo the output on every 50 loops?

Tags: php, foreach

I am using a foreach statement that loops around 1000 and more times. I was wondering if there is a way to echo the results like every 50 loops until it reach the 1000 and stop.

The purpose of it is because I am writing a crawler, I want to see some results occasionally of what the script found instead of wait for many time for the whole thing.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DhruvPathak's solution kind of works, but the correct answer would be something like

```
$freq = 50;
for($i = 0 ;$i < 1000 ;$i++)
{
   /* some work here */

    if($i % $freq  == ($freq-1))
      echo  "my message \n";
}
if($i % $freq  != ($freq-1))
   echo  "last echo \n";
```

In this solution, the echo is done AFTER each 50 (rather than doing it after the first item and then after each 50 items), and a final echo is done at the end if needed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use "%" operator in if condition.

```
for($i = 0 ;$i < 1000 ;$i++)
{
   /* some work here */

    if($i % 50  == 0)
      echo  "my message \n";

}
```

Comment: So it was that easy! Thank you, I have to wait 12 mins to accept it though.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to keep a counter and check it in every iteration:

```
$i = 1;

foreach ($something as $current) {

    if ($i % 50 == 0) {
        echo "Iteration: $i \n" ;
    }

    $i++ ;

}
```

The [modulo operator %](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) is useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this one

```
$i = 0;
    while($i <1000):
      // do your work

        if($i % 50  == 0){
          echo  "message \n";
         }
       $i++ ;
   endwhile;
```